# iPhone - App always starts with an empty white screen?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I can't get my iPhone app to display any of the content on startup.
Any idea what's wrong here?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{ 
     HomeViewController *t = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
     [self.window addSubview:t.view];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     // I tried the following in case the problem is my
     //view controller but nothing shows up at all
     UISegmentedControl *t = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] init];
     [self.window addSubview:t];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your view controller implements `loadView`, you should load the view from a NIB file with `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

A segmented control should be initialized with `initWithItems:`. You should also assign a frame to the control.

Comment: And actually that was my problem i left the ".m" in the name of my nib name "HomeViewController.m.xib" i renamed it correctly and problem solved

Comment: initWithNibName is not required if the nib file has the exact same name as the viewcontroller

Comment: @aryaxt: It's true that you don't have to specify a NIB name in that case. However, IMO you should use `initWithNibName:bundle:` (with both arguments being `nil`) anyway because it is `UIViewController`'s designated initializer.